# Problem with using OnIdiom on VS for Mac using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac, detection-idiom

I have always used this the same way and it always worked. After an update I keep getting an error. Can someone help me out?

[image]

This is the error I get.
[image]

Comment: Hi, what's the version of xamarin forms used in project, whether it's the latest version?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Xamarin.Android
Version: 11.2.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)

Comment: Hi, it works in my local site. Visual Studoo for Mac(`8.8.9`), and nuget of Xamarin Forms(`5.0.0.2012`).